# Wrapping partially bolded and italicized main title in ggpubr - ggerrorplot

Tags: r, ggpubr

I cannot get any of the solutions for wrapping a main plot title to work with a title that includes some bold and italicized words. Among several other solutions that did nothing, I've tried stringr and manually creating a line break, but stringr includes the "bold," etc. text and the manual line breaks either produce nothing or create very strange breaks [strange manual break](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wQgij.png) (I've tried them at several places to see if anything worked).

Sorry for the clumsy code-I am a biology grad student and pretty new to R.

```
mainplotlabel4 <- c(expression(paste(bold("Figure 5"), italic(" Species with long name"), " Long fake name virginica response all things"), italic(" Shorter species"), " Sepal Length Only Purple Long Fake Name"))
setosa.sepal.dotplot <- ggerrorplot(data = iris, x = "Species", y= "Sepal.Length", add = "jitter", error.plot =  "linerange", add.params = list(color="darkolivegreen2", size=1.5), xlab = 'Treatment', ylab = "Sepal Length", main = mainplotlabel4, ylim = c(0, 10), width=1, ggtheme = theme_dark())
setosa.sepal.dotplot + rotate_x_text(45)
```

Comment: Please include all the packages that you are using. `ggerrorplot` is not a base function of ggplot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Going off the [ggtext package webiste](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/ggtext/readme/README.html):

```
library(ggpubr)
library(ggtext)
library(tidyverse)

iris %>%
  ggerrorplot(
    x = "Species",
    y = "Sepal.Length", 
    add = "jitter", 
    error.plot =  "linerange", 
    add.params = list(color = "darkolivegreen2", size = 1.5), 
    xlab = 'Treatment', 
    ylab = "Sepal Length",
    ylim = c(0, 10), 
    width = 1, 
    ggtheme = theme_dark()
    ) + 
  labs(
    title = "<b>Figure 5</b> <i>Species with long name</i> Long fake name virginica response all things <i>Shorter species</i> Sepal Length Only Purple Long Fake Name") +
  theme(
    plot.title.position = "plot",
    plot.title = element_textbox_simple(
      size = 13,
      lineheight = 1,
      padding = margin(5.5, 5.5, 5.5, 5.5),
      margin = margin(0, 0, 5.5, 0)
    )
  ) +
  rotate_x_text(45)
```

You can manually include line breaks in the title using `<br>`.

[Final graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ekAnE.png)

Comment: Great, thank you so much! I knew there had to be a simpler solution. That ggtext package README is the best one I've seen for a package-all of the ones I've used have no or few, unhelpful examples.

Comment: No problem. If my answer was helpful, consider [accepting it](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).